# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' from vendor.js in Angular 15

Tags: javascript, migration, angular15

I upgraded from Angular 9 to 15. After the migration when I try to run the application in localhost, I am getting the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'  from  vendor.js"

in the below line.

```
 private _applyAnimationRefDelays(
      animationsRefsOptions: (AnimationOptions|null)[], context: AnimationTimelineContext,
      innerContext: AnimationTimelineContext) {
    for (const animationRefOptions of animationsRefsOptions) {
      const animationDelay = animationRefOption**s?.del**ay;  //**Error from this line. (unable to recognize the '.' )**
      if (animationDelay) {
        const animationDelayValue = typeof animationDelay === 'number' ?
            animationDelay :
            resolveTimingValue(interpolateParams(
                animationDelay, animationRefOptions?.params ?? {}, context.errors));
        innerContext.delayNextStep(animationDelayValue);
      }
    }
  }
```

In dev machine,
When with Node 14.20 ->  working fine in localhost,
With Node 16.16 -> Getting the above error.

Comment: Do you really have `**` in the line? Please post the actual code, highlighting doesn't work in code blocks.

Comment: The error implies that it doesn't understand the `?.` optional chaining syntax. That was added in Node.js 14, so it should work in both 14.20 and 16.16.

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks for the Suggestion.  Found the issue.  It is due to older version of chrome which do not understand the optional chaining syntax. 
After upgrading to the latest browser version, issue is resolved now.

Comment: The question says this is running in node.js, not the browser.